# SQL Server - Função split

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

O objetivo é fazer, em SQL Server, uma função *Split* (por ',') da coluna `EixoX` onde o `TipoGrafico` seja diferente de *'StockChart'*. Ou seja, caso o `TipoGrafico` seja diferente de *'StockChart'* aí é que devo fazer o split do conteúdo da coluna `EixoX`.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer?

Desde já obrigado :)

Comment: Você quer substituir quando `TipoGrafico` for igual a `StockChart` para o valor de `EixoX`? É isso?

Comment: @RBZ Por exemplo, quando o TipoGrafico for diferente de 'StockChart', aí é que devo fazer o Split do conteúdo da coluna EixoX :)

Comment: O "split" já está funcionando? Se sim, edita a pergunta e coloca sua query.

Comment: @RBZ Não, isto porque ainda tenho que criar a função :/ mas para simplificar vou deixar a condições para efectuar o Split:

Select * from tbGraficoConsultas
where IDConfiguracoesConsultas = xxx 
and TipoGrafico <> 'StockChart'

Comment: qual a versão do seu banco?

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães é o SQL Server 2014

Comment: Tenta dessa forma: `SELECT TipoGrafico, (CASE WHEN TipoGrafico <> 'StockChart' THEN STRING_SPLIT(EixoX, ',') ELSE EixoX END) EixoX_
FROM tabela`

Comment: Ou dessa: `SELECT TipoGrafico, (CASE TipoGrafico  WHEN 'StockChart' THEN EixoX 
 ELSE STRING_SPLIT(EixoX, ',')  END) EixoX_ FROM tabela`

Comment: @RBZ infelizmente não consigo executar essa query, aparece este erro: "'STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name.". Acho que deve ser por causa da versão 2014 não ter essa função embutida :/

Comment: É, terá que criar uma função pelo visto: [Link1](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/) , [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Comment: @RBZ Obrigado pela ajuda, vou experimentar :)

Comment: O select irá se manter, mudando somente o `STRING_SPLIT`: `SELECT TipoGrafico, (CASE TipoGrafico WHEN 'StockChart' THEN EixoX ELSE nomeFuncao(EixoX, ',') END) EixoX_ FROM tabela`.

Comment: `STRING_SPLIT` [só está disponível a partir da versão 2016 do SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), e a versão que está sendo usada segundo o comentário é a 2014. Tem vários exemplos de funções para fazer o split na internet, aqui uma delas: [how-to-split-comma-delimited-string](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4126a010-6885-4eb0-b79c-c798c90edb85/how-to-split-comma-delimited-string)

Comment: @RicardoPontual Exato, infelizmente não tenho condições para usar essa função. Obrigado pela ajuda Ricardo :)

Answer (score 2):

Tenho uma função pronta se resolver pra você.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_split] (@String NVARCHAR(4000), @Delimiter NCHAR(1)) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
```

Comment: Só faltou faze o select com a necessidade dele. Completa aí pra ficar 100%! rs ✌️

Comment: Nice, obrigado! Vou adaptar às minhas necessidades :D